# text with dynamic number of links embedded

Tags: dynamic, text, wicket, hyperlink

I have some texts that I'm fetching from a database that must be shown to users. Each text has some links to other texts that I need to render. Links are dynamic, meaning I cannot know before hand how many of these links will be rendered (and where in the text). Just to give a quicke example:

T1
This is the first example of text LINK1 to give a LINK2 brief idea of my problem

T2
This is yet another LINK3 example of my problem LINK4 can anybody help LINK5 ?

What's the best way to do this in Wicket? Without pre-cooked markup?

Answer (score 0):

A) Just don't do it with Wicket, use any templating solution you like (take a look at VelocityPanel).

B) If your links are already final in your texts, use SmartLinkMultilineLabel

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [SmartLinkLabel](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.5/org/apache/wicket/extensions/markup/html/basic/SmartLinkLabel.html) as suggested by svenmeier.

If your links are already present in the text as hyperlinks you can use it out of the box. If you need to post-process the links you can provide a custom [LinkParser](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.5/org/apache/wicket/extensions/markup/html/basic/LinkParser.html):

```
@Override
protected ILinkParser getLinkParser() {
    final LinkParser parser = new LinkParser();
    return parser.addLinkRenderStrategy(YOUR_PATTERN, new ILinkRenderStrategy() {
        @Override
        public String buildLink(final String linkTarget) {
            // build the link from the target matched by the pattern
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Guys, thanks for the suggestions! I will delve into SmartLinkLabel first.

Actually, those are not URLs. I need those links to trigger an action: for instance, opening a window with additional related text fetched from the DB.